# Error occurs when compiling with GCC

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, makefile

I am attempting to compile a C program with multiple files on window platform. However, when I make it, errors are occurred. I have already tried to modify command in makefile but still could not fix it.
This is my GCC command:

```
gcc -o "SYSMONTR" $(OBJPATH)/chkdsksp ../chkdsksp.c -g -I"$(DB2PATH)/include" -I"$(MYLIBDIR)" $(MYIQDIR)/iqclilib.a $(OBJPATH)/icrou.a -lc -ldb2 -lnsl -L"$(DB2PATH)/lib"
```

This is result:

```
gcc -o "SYSMONTR" ../../iLINKOBJ/chkdsksp ../chkdsksp.c -g -I"C:/Program Files/IBM/SQLLIB/include" -I"../../iLINKCLIB" ../../iLINKIQOBJ/iqclilib.a ../../iLINKOBJ/icrou.a -lc -ldb2 -lnsl -L"C:/Program Files/IBM/SQLLIB/lib"
../../iLINKOBJ/chkdsksp: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:49: recipe for target `SYSMONTR' failed
make: *** [SYSMONTR] Error 1
```

What could cause such error and what should I do with it? Using cygwin on Window (IDE: Eclipse).
Any supports will be appreciated.

Comment: Your command is bad.  The `-o` flag takes a single argument which is the file that should be created as output by the compiler.  So `-o SYSMONTR $(OBJPATH)/chkdsksp` means "link a program and name it `SYSMONTR` and as part of it pull in the file `$(OBJPATH)/chkdsksp`, which is probably a program.  You can't link a program into another program.  I suspect what you WANTED to say was `-DSYSMONTR -o $(OBJPATH)/chkdsksp` instead.

Comment: chkdsksp is an object file, not a program.
If using Mad's command, another error occured:
"iLINKIQOBJ/iqclilib.a: file format not recognized; treating as linker script"
Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: How do you know that `chkdsksp` is an object file? Do you build it? If so, is there a reason you don't name it `chkdsksp.o`?

Comment: @Beta: I got this file from another team. This C program is currently running on AIX platform. My work is compile on Window. So I don't mind what exactly it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `chkdsksp` is an object file built by another team to run on AIX, you cannot expect it to function -- or even be recognized by your compiler -- on Cygwin. You must contact that team and get a) the source code or b) a version of the object file compiled for your platform (and *tested*).

Comment: Thanks Beta, this may the answer that I expected. I will contact with them right now. By the way, if there are any problems, please help me to solve. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: Dear Beta, could I get your Skype ID or Gtalk ID for asking you further information?

Comment: @user2767584: I'm happy to help, but I have neither skype nor gtalk, and you can't yet participate in stackOverflow chat. For now, if you need info in a hurry, comment on this answer and I'll reply (and later we can delete our comments).